# How to add a custom path to : " ls -d */ "

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, cut, ls

Issue : The code works fine, it lists folders with "numerical names" in a reversed order, however I would have to be in the same directory. I would like to add a custom path to it so that I do not have to be in the same directory.

```
ls -d */ |  cut -d '/' -f 1 | sort -nr
```

I tried adding " `/test/path` " to the code above, but without success.

```
ls -d */ /test/path/ |  cut -d '/' -f 1 | sort -nr
```

Update : I do not know why "test2" is being printed at the bottom in this scenario. I am using `SliTaz Linux 5.0` I can not figure out the `shell` version.

```
root@s1:/# mkdir /test
root@s1:/# mkdir /test/test2
root@s1:/# cd /test/test2/
root@s1:/test/test2# mkdir 1 2 3 10
root@s1:/test/test2# touch test.txt
root@s1:/test/test2# ls -d /test/test2/*/ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr
10
3
2
1
test2
root@s1:/test/test2#
```

Update 2 : 
On my cloud server which uses "Alpine Linux" version "3" I believe, there does not seem to be a problem, the code works ok.

```
test:/# mkdir /test
test:/# mkdir /test/test2
test:/# cd /test/test2
test:/test/test2# mkdir 1 2 3 10
test:/test/test2# touch test.txt
test:/test/test2# ls -d /test/test2/*/ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr
10
3
2
1
test:/test/test2#
```

Comment: What does `ls -d /test/test2/*/ | awk 1` produce on the problematic machine? The accepted answer should be portable; I would speculate that your directory tree contains more than you reveal.

Comment: @tripleee, It all looks normal. `/test/test2/1/
/test/test2/10/
/test/test2/2/
/test/test2/3/
/test/test2/test.txt`  Perhaps for portability, I can use " `test=$(cd /test/test2/ ; ls -d */ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr)`" and .. `echo $test` but maybe that is missing `new lines`.

Comment: @SümerKolçak, I guess `test.txt` is not dir? It shouldn't be getting printed when typing `ls -d /test/test2/*/`. I searched net and it says you machine has `ash` as the default shell. I have not got any good idea on how you do that in `ash`.

Comment: @Mihir, I just noticed that, you are correct. @tripleee, I take it back, there seems to be a problem, it lists the file as a folder. Does not happen on my cloud server with Alpine Linux : `ls -d /test/test2/*/` `/test/test2/1/   /test/test2/10/  /test/test2/2/   /test/test2/3/`

Comment: I can't repro that, though my Alpine has Busybox, not Ash: https://pastebin.com/qUYDKY7J

Comment: Wrong image, but I get the same for `slitaz/slitaz-base`

Comment: @tripleee, my home computer using SliTaz Linux 5 shows this for `ls --version`  result : `BusyBox v1.31.0` my cloud server using Alpine Linux , shows `BusyBox v1.30.1`

Comment: The `slitaz` project on Docker doesn't seem to have any fresh images, the ones I could find are 2+ years old. Seems like a bug in that particular environment anyway.

Comment: @tripleee,  The reason I use Slitaz Linux 5 (`slitaz-rolling-core.iso`) is because it works so perfectly with my home computer which uses an old `Gigabyte brand`motherboard with `32 bit only` abilities. the fonts and everything is just so awesome, I can even read the smallest fonts and text. I tried installing it on a cloud server, but of course I had to use a "64 bit" version. I could not setup the networking, I gave up on it. I would want to use Alpine Linux at home also but it lacks GUI features. As a server it seems to be very `fast loading`.

Comment: That's your prerogative, of course (as is the `funny` formatting); just saying that a bug in one OS does not really suffice to make the solution "non-portable". If that particular bug in that particular OS is crucial for you, I'm sure you can figure out a workaround.

Comment: No repro in `docker run --rm -it busybox:1-31` either.

Comment: @tripleee, I came to the conclusion that "Slitaz Linux 5" is less popular than "Alpine Linux", therefore the problem is actually more specific to my style rather than generic world. That is why I chose the answer although it did not work perfectly with my home computer, however the workaround can work, which is inside of the comments of the "selected answer".  The workaround being : `test=$(cd /test/test2/ ; ls -d */ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr)`"  which was also partially given to me by the user that posted the answer, however via comment rather than in the answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -d /test/path/*/ |  cut -d '/' -f 1 | sort -nr
```

Although `cut` won't work the way you intend to use it.

Instead use this:

```
ls -d /test/path/*/ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr
```

Also to avoid nullglob, set this before:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

So that if no directories exist, it doesn't result into error.

I am not sure about the reason the above command doesn't work on `SliTaz Linux 5.0`, but as discussed, this can be done instead:

```
cd /test/path/ ; ls -d */ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr ; cd "$OLDPWD"
```

or

```
(cd /test/path/ ; ls -d */ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr)
```

Comment: This one is also printing "`test2`" at the end.  There is no "test2" in the "test2" folder. `ls -d /test/test2/*/ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr`

Comment: @SümerKolçak, can't reproduce, what shell version do you use?

Comment: Also whats the output of `ls -d /test/test2/*/ `, can you update that in your question?

Comment: I have updated the question. And the output for `ls -d /test/test2/*/` is : 
`/test/test2/1/       /test/test2/2/        /test/test2/test.txt
/test/test2/10/       /test/test2/3/
`

Comment: I am selecting your answer as "chosen answer" because your code is working on my cloud server which uses "Alpine Linux". So perhaps your code will work at other places too, maybe the issue is with my home computer which uses "Slitaz Linux 5" , I added "Update 2" to my question, to show that the code is working on "Alpine Linux"

Comment: @SümerKolçak, could you try `(cd /test/test2/ ; ls -d */ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr)` on your machine.

Comment: It  works okay with that method : `root@s1:/# (cd /test/test2/ ; ls -d */ | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | sort -nr)` result : 
`10
3
2
1`